# Android apk logs in installed devices

Tags: android

I want to store all the runtime info and error logs of my apk within sdcard folder `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), /myapk/logs/myapk_date.log)`. How do I achieve this ?

Extra information - My app will be installed in plug PCs that start on boot, occupy full screen and play certain content sent from the server. This will be the only app any user would see as there would be no user interaction. The apk would upload the logs to the server by EOD.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.mindpipe.android/android-logging-log4j

Use this jar file

Here is sample code:

```
public class ALogger {
    public static org.apache.log4j.Logger getLogger(Class clazz) {
        final LogConfigurator logConfigurator = new LogConfigurator();
        logConfigurator.setFileName(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "log/file.log");
        logConfigurator.setRootLevel(Level.ALL);
        logConfigurator.setLevel("org.apache", Level.ALL);
        logConfigurator.setUseFileAppender(true);
        logConfigurator.setFilePattern("%d %-5p [%c{2}]-[%L] %m%n");
        logConfigurator.setMaxFileSize(1024 * 1024 * 5);
        logConfigurator.setImmediateFlush(true);
        logConfigurator.configure();
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(clazz);
        return log;
    }
}
```

In your code, replace the below lines:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure(MY_PROP_FILE);
logger = Logger.getLogger( MyClaZZ.class );
With:

logger = ALogger.getLogger(MyClazz.class);
```

Reference: Using Log4j in android

Comment: which version of log4j core jars would be compatible with the above mentioned android-logging-log4j ?